# What to do for New Year's Eve - or on New Year's Eve?

Tags: prepositions

> What are you going to do **for** New Year's Eve?

and

> I started worrying about what to do **on** New Year's Eve.

These are example sentences from Google Books. What is the difference between the use of **for** and **on**?

Is "to do something **for** New Year's Eve" fully synonymous with "to do something **on** New Year's Eve"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These two sentences are very similar and there is only a subtle semantic difference between them. Most people probably wouldn't think twice at hearing either one in any circumstance.

'For' implies the actions being taken are caused by or in response to something (in this case, New Year's Eve). This emphasizes New Year's Eve as a special event, rather than just another day. You would use this to talk about things that happen specifically on account of or because of New Year.

'On' is how we generally refer to times and places (on that day, on top of the hill, etc). This puts less emphasis on New Year's Eve as a special day by referring to it just as you would any other day. You would probably use this to talk about things that could happen any day.

If I were telling someone about small details of my plans for the day, I would use 'on':

On New Year's Eve, I will wake up, eat breakfast, go for a walk and drink Champagne.
(These are all things that could happen on any day, but they happen to be on New Year's Eve)

If I were telling someone about traditions and things that make the New Years holiday special, I would use 'for':

For New Year's Eve, I will get together with my friends and make resolutions to improve my life.
(These are things that are done for the purpose of, or because of the New Year's Eve holiday)

Comment: Curiously, although the same nuanced difference applies to ***for** Christmas*, the "temporal" version there is ***at** Christmas*. But ***on*** and ***at*** are both "spatial/locational" metaphoric forms pressed into service as temporal references to *a point in **time***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I believe that would be in British usage; as an American I would only say *on Christmas*.

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus The difference is that we would say *at this time* but *on this day*; so, it's roughly equivalent to saying *at Christmas time*.

Comment: I (BrEng) would allow "at Christmas" but "on Christmas Day" as @WinnieNicklaus says the difference is that the latter is about a day not a time. The "Eve" of New Year's Eve functions in the same way.

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus: Unless followed by another word (such as *day, eve*), [***at** Christmas we {did something}*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+Christmas+we%2Con+Christmas+we&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20Christmas%20we%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20Christmas%20we%3B%2Cc0) is still the more common version, even in AmE. But you're right insofar as ***on** Christmas* does at least actually *exist* in AmE - whereas it's virtually unknown in BrE.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Are you thinking about (and/or, is the Google books sample typically referring to) the Christmas season or just the day of December 25 (January 7)?

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus: I wasn't particularly thinking of *either* - just pointing out that ***at** Christmas* is far more common among *all* Anglophones than ***on** Christmas*. Maybe some AmE speakers might reserve ***on*** for the single day, and ***at*** for the more extended period - but being American yourself you presumably know more about that than me. It seems to me BrE usage is pretty consistent about observing the distinction Luke makes about ***at** a "time"* vs ***on** a "day"*.

Answer (score 5):

> What are you going to do anything special **for** New Year's Eve?

This is asking what you will do *because* of the holiday. This is often used to describe preparations or actions occuring because of the holiday.

> I will make special cookies **for** New Year's Day.
>   Are you planning a party **for** New Year's Eve?

If you say:

> What are you going to do **on** New Year's Eve?

you are specifically asking what you will be doing on that day.

> I will go to that party **on** New Year's Eve.
>   We will have a special dinner **on** New Year's Eve.

Comment: The two questions could get different responses, and this answer does a good job of explaining why. _What are you doing **on** New Year's Eve?_ Answer: "I'm working." Now, change that to, _What are you doing **for** New Year's Eve?_ The new answer might be: "***Nothing***; I'm working". (You might add the word "nothing" to your answer to that latter question, because it's asking about _how you are going to celebrate_, not necessarily what you'll be doing on that day – and you won't be celebrating.)

Answer (score 4):

When speaking about holidays, both ***on*** and ***for*** sound natural and are virtually synonymous.

> What are you doing for [your celebration of] New Year's Eve?
>
> What are you doing on [the day of] New Year's Eve?

When we're talking about normal days (not holidays), ***on*** is preferred, and ***for*** does not sound natural:

> What are you doing on Saturday?
>
> <s>What are you doing for Saturday?</s>

In the second case, the use of "for" suggests "for the celebration of", which suggests that the upcoming Saturday is a holiday. (If Saturday *is* New Year's Eve, or the day of my birthday party, or some other special occasion, then "for Saturday" would be correct.)

Comment: Oh, that's why **for** is used! There's the implied "celerbation of". And I was wondering.. Thanks, apsillers!.

Answer (score 1):

In India, we have [Diwali](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diwali) holidays. Take a note that there are 'holidayS' and not a holiday. We often ask each other...

> What is your plan ***for*** Diwali ~ I think I'll visit my hometown. I may then plan for good shopping.

On the other hand,

> What is your plan ***on*** Diwali ~ I'll be at home celebrating with my family.

Taking a sensible note from this, I can say that 'something **for** some festival' talks about the 'event' as a whole and 'something **on** festival day' talks **more** about the activity on that particular day. So, understanding the nuance of `something for festival` and `something on festival day` clarifies the matter.

Comment: Last line clears the concept. No need to read anything else.